# phalcon Cookies Management do not work

Tags: php, cookies, phalcon

```
   $this->cookies->set(  
        "hbl",
        "some value",
        time()+3600*24
    );


    $value = "my cookie value";
    setcookie("TestCookie",$value, time()+3600*24);
```

phalcon cookie do not work,  i use raw php cookie, it work,
i loot at chrome cookie and find that phalcon cookie do not work

cookie has inject in framework default

```
  $di->set(
        "crypt",
        function () {
            $crypt = new Crypt();

            $crypt->setKey('#1dj8$=dp?.ak//j1V$'); // 使用你自己的key！

            return $crypt;
        }
    );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwfId.png)

Comment: i solve it by invoke send method  eq: $this->cookies->send()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom `session` service, phalcon cookies won't work until you create static method `isStarted()` for it.

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/http/cookie.zep#L249